# ARIMA model with measurement error

Tags: forecasting, arima, measurement-error

I'm interested in forecasting a time series $m_t$ which is contaminated with measurement error $e_t$, so the observed time series is $y_t = m_t + e_t$. I can suppose $m_t$ and $e_t$ are independent and $e_t$ is basically white noise.

The question is, if I fit an ARIMA model to $y_t$, forecasts will be of $y_t$ or of $m_t$?

Comment: I'm sorry I do not underatnd what $m_t$ is? Is it a variable and if so why then is the proces ARIMA, where are the AR and MA terms?

Comment: $m_t$ is an aggregate which is not directly observed but estimated. For example a price index sampled from a limited, but representative, number of articles.

Comment: I still do not quite understand where the AR and MA terms are? It is unclear what you are asking because in its present form $y_t = m_t + e_t$ is not ARIMA and has no parameters to be estimated. So it is unclear how you plan to estimate the model as ARIMA.

Comment: Generally, if you fit a model and make forecasts with it, they will be forecasts of the dependent variable in the model, here $y_t$.

Comment: @JesperHybel: The ARIMA model would be fitted on $y_t$ which is the only observed series. The relation $y_t = m_t + e_t$ is to make explicit that $m_t$ is aproximated by $y_t$ with error $e_t$.

Comment: @RichardHardy: That's right, but I think there are two process here. If $\hat{Y_T}$ is the forecast at time T based on the ARIMA model, then $E(\hat{Y_T})=E_1(E_2(\hat{Y_T}|y_1, y_2, ..., y_t))=E_1(y_T)=m_T$, where $E_2$ is expectation of the ARIMA process and $E_1$ is expectantion of the error process. Is my argument correct?

Comment: @Pacorro, the conditional mean of $y_t$ equals the conditional mean of $m_t$, so if you are only interested in an optimal point forecast of $m_t$ under square loss, the model is just fine for that. But if you want a density forecast, an interval forecast or a forecast under some other loss function (different from square loss), the model might not give an optimal forecast for $m_t$ even when it would give one for $y_t$.